# How to search 50% to 80% from a database column which has contained lots of paragraph text

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to search 50% to 80% similar text from a database column.

The rows of that particular column has contained lots of paragraph text. From this text I need to find out which are all the rows has similar text in that particular column.

Using SQL I have to solve that.

Example:
Suppose, I have 3 text in a column (Sample_text) of a table. I want to search 50 to 80 percent similarity text form a given text.

1. a. The Safety gate combined with one gate.
   b. The Safety gate combined with three gates.
   c. The Safety gate separated with others gates.

If I search through the text, "The Safety gate combined with one gate" then it will show all the three above text. Because those three text have more than 70 percent similarity in between those above three text.

But,

2. a. Important! save for (new AMII).
   b. Important! keep instruction (AMII).

Those couple of text does not have the 50 percent similarity in between that.
So, it will show nothing.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What have you tried already?

Comment: Please edit your question with the following (1) A tag of the database you are using; (2) Sample data; (3) Desired results; (4) A problem statement that is clear; and (5) Sample code to solve the problem, if any.

Comment: You need define "similar text".

Comment: I have tried like keyword to get that. But here it has not working. Because there are to many sentences in a single row. so I am not able to solve that.

Comment: If it is possible then please provide me a solution. Because i am a fresher in database. If it is a search code then it will be ok. like google search.

Comment: And please show your stored procedure if you have any code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating text similarity can be an incredibly hard problem depending on how you define it.  Look at the functions in [UTL_MATCH](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_match.htm#ARPLS352).  They don't give exactly the results you want, but it's a good starting point.

**EDIT_DISTANCE**

```
--89
select utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(
    s1 => 'The Safety gate combined with one gate.',
    s2 => 'The Safety gate combined with three gates.')
from dual;

--60
select utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(
    s1 => 'The Safety gate combined with one gate.',
    s2 => 'Safety gate separated with others gates.')
from dual;

--58
select utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(
    s1 => 'Important! save for (new AMII).',
    s2 => 'Important! keep instruction (AMII).')
from dual;
```

**JARO_WINKLER**

```
--94
select utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(
    s1 => 'The Safety gate combined with one gate.',
    s2 => 'The Safety gate combined with three gates.')
from dual;

--69
select utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(
    s1 => 'The Safety gate combined with one gate.',
    s2 => 'Safety gate separated with others gates.')
from dual;

--88
select utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(
    s1 => 'Important! save for (new AMII).',
    s2 => 'Important! keep instruction (AMII).')
from dual;
```

Comment: I does not want to show how many percentage has similar between two text. I want if i put one string then it will show how many similar text, which are 50 to 80 percent similar with that given text present in that particular column.

Comment: If you want to filter the results, you can add the function to the `WHERE` clause.  For example, `select * from ... where utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(text1, text2) between 50 and 80;`